# Installing a Plugin ( Which is already manually uploaded )

Tags: plugins, installation

I need to install wordpress plugin for placing source codes to my blogs.

See, the following snapshot describes that I have already uploaded plugin to proper place.
I didn't make even a single change to that directory & It is uploaded without any intact. What should be the next step for activating this plugin ? ( I am using my own domain )

[image]

I have followed steps 1 & 2 from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Manual_Plugin_Installation). I am confused what to do for further steps.

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge.

Sugar.

Comment: in the image you provided does it also show a .php file? this file will then give the plugin details onto wp-admin >> plugins dashboard, where you can activate it, where is this plugin from?

Comment: @Martin - I have installed - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/installation/

Comment: @Martin - After installation, I tried to find "wp-admin>>plugins dashboad". But I didn't fine syntaxHighlighter there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from here you have two options available:

1) Dont know if you have done this already but you will need to go to **wp-admin >> plugins** (its at the left of the wp-admin dashboard beneath "appearance") from here if all is well with your manual upload you should see your plugin title in the main area, just click activate plugin.

2) If its not there, then remove the files you have uploaded and go back to wp-admin plugins, at the top you see an area where it says "Plugins" and a button that says "Add New", click "add new" button and the page will re-load. Use the Search for the plugin from the wp repository (search for its title) and grab it from there, just follow the onscreen instructions.. very easy..

Comment: Well ! Mr. @Martin. Thank  you very much for your quick reply. Installing plugins using wordpress itself that I know. I am facing connection problems. I mean - wordpress is not able to connect FTP-mysite. I provided proper credentials there, though it says - There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.